# conky: proper column alignment

Tags: conky

Say I want something like the following in my `.conkyrc`

```
NAME                PID       CPU%      MEM%
${top name 1} ${top pid 1}   ${top cpu 1}    ${top mem 1}
${top name 2} ${top pid 2}   ${top cpu 2}    ${top mem 2}
${top name 3} ${top pid 3}   ${top cpu 3}    ${top mem 3}
${top name 4} ${top pid 4}   ${top cpu 4}    ${top mem 4}
```

Do I have to align the columns manually by adding space, or is there a way to tell conky to align things in columns. With fewer columns, I could just use `$alignc` and `$alignr` but I can't do that here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you stick to left-aligned columns or a non-proportional font, `${goto N}` works.

```
NAME${goto 100}PID${goto 200}  CPU%${goto 300}MEM%
${top name 1}${goto 100}${top pid 1}${goto 200}${top cpu 1}${goto 300}${top mem 1}
```

For right alignment, you can try playing with `alignr` and `offset`.

Comment: Since the names are longer than the other columns, I used 150,200,250 rather than 100,200,300...

Comment: Is a certain package needed for `${goto x}` functionality? On my system, all text appearing after a `goto` statement (regardless of the value used for the positional offset `x`) fails to display.

Comment: @user001 Not that I know of. Make sure that you aren't overriding the value of `TERM`. One route to debug this is to look at what control sequences Conky is emitting with `strace -ewrite -p$(pidof conky)`. [Ask a question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you don't know how to make sense of this.

Comment: `conky -D` might come in handy as well perhaps (will put conky into debug mode, letting you peek way more deeply into its inner workings, and maybe giving you a clue what your build of conky is "allergic" against)